# Returning output values from PROC that has multiple queries using SQLSRV

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I have a stored procedure that has four SELECT statements and a single UPDATE statement. The first SELECT statement returns a result set (which I can retrieve fine.) The second, third and fourth SELECT statements all return OUTPUT variables but I'm not able to retrieve their values. I understand that I need to use a `sqlsrv_next_result()` to get past the result set but I'm not sure if I need additional ones for the other three SELECT statements. In other words, do I need a `sqlsrv_next_result()` for just the SELECT statement that returns the result set, do I need four (one for each SELECT statement) or maybe five (an additional one to get past all of them)? Note: I have a `SET NOCOUNT ON` command in the PROC because of the UPDATE statement so that shouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the source of my problem was initializing a couple of the output variables incorrectly, setting them as integers instead of varchars. With that now fixed, it appears that the answer to my question is that I need a single `sqlsrv_next_result` for each SELECT statement that returns a result set, not for those that return OUTPUT variables.